# R system() doesn't behave like cmd itself

Tags: r, command-line, stdin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm doing some bioinformatics analysis in Rstudio, but something strange happens when using system(). I'm also using Windows Subsystem for Linux, so I can run a UNIX executable in my Windows **cmd** like so:

```
bash -c "./parasail-master/build/parasail_aligner -a sw_trace_striped_sat -f SSWtemplate.fa -q SSWtest.fa -O EMBOSS -d >OUT.txt"
```

Don't worry about the specifics: what's important is that I use *bash -c* to indicate I want to use the UNIX bash, and I'm running the executable parasail_aligner. It all works out, and I get the nice output file "OUT.txt".

Now, since I'm doing my analysis in Rstudio, I want to execute this directly from an R script, like so:

```
system('bash -c "./parasail-master/build/parasail_aligner -a sw_trace_striped_sat -f SSWtemplate.fa -q SSWtest.fa -O EMBOSS -d >OUTER.txt"')
```

So: just give it as an argument to **system()**? But this gives the following error:

```
input file, query file, and stdin detected; max inputs is 2
```

This is obviously an error specifically generated by parasail_aligner. The funny thing is: **I don't get this error at all from cmd directly, but I do get it when running the command in R using system()**. Does anyone have any idea why something like this can happen at all? I would expect system() to just give its argument to cmd, but clearly it doesn't do this... Running the command in a command terminal opened in Rstudio also works fine, it is specifically system() that seems to mess up.

I'm terribly sorry if this question is vague, but I can't give you a simple example which you could use to replicate the error. I've been using system() for a while now and I've never had this kind of problem. I am on Windows and I've found some people online that say you should use shell() instead of system(), but doing so just gives me the same error.

Maybe it has something to do with this "**stdin**" thing the error mentions and how R/RStudio handles this, I don't know. But parasail seems to think I give it an extra input "stdin": it is true I give an Input File and a Query File (see error message), but I don't know what this "stdin" is.

If anyone has any ideas about what could be behind this strange behaviour of system(), I'm all ears. I understand that helping me is difficult since I can't give a simple example in which the problem occurs, but I hope someone might know what could be the problem anyway

**UPDATE (answer?)**: so, I managed to resolve the issue, like so:

```
system('bash -c "./parasail-master/build/parasail_aligner -a sw_trace_striped_sat < SSWtemplate.fa -f SSWtest.fa -O EMBOSS -d >OUTER.txt"')
```

I did some searching about stdin, and (forgive me if what I say sounds amateur, I'm not really familiar with UNIX or command line) found out its "symbol" is **<**. So you can see in the code above, I changed the way I give in my inputs "SSWtemplate" and "SSWtest", giving one of them using "<", and this solves the problem.

I have no idea why this happens. Especially since it only happens when calling the command from inside RStudio, and not when doing so from cmd. If anyone can clarify this further (i.e. why and how functions like system() and shell() seem to mess with stdin), it would be a big help. Otherwise, I'll just answer this to my own question and leave it at that.

Comment: Does using `shell` instead of `system` solve your particular problem?

Comment: @Hugh: no, it does not. It just returns the same error.

Comment: Have looked at `system2`? Also, test from R console (from R) and from RStudio (on Windows, RStudio console is slightly different than the R console).